# CVAE on CIFAR10 Dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I was running the code from the following repository.(https://github.com/debtanu177/CVAE_MNIST/blob/master/train_cvae.py)
I was wondering if there was a way to adapt this to run on the CIFAR10 Dataset. Since the images are 32x32 instead of 28x28, how could I change the structure of the convolutional and fully connected layers of the model and also the encoder and decoder, as well as any other parts of the Model which would need to be adjusted?

Answer (score 0):

Convolutional operations do not change on image size, unless the image is smaller than the kernel. The only thing you have have to change in your code is the output of the decoder so that it's last layer is 32x32 instead of 28x28. The encoder can stay the same.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, but I am unsure how I would change the output of the decoder so the last layer is 32x32 instead of 28x28, as I also do not know where the last layer is set to 28x28. Could you check the repository and let me know which line of code I should modify? Thanks!

Comment: Since this system has both encoder and decoder, you need to modify the number of convolutional layers and their params to adapt to your target image size.  Read more in [Conv2d docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) and [TransposeConv2d docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d.html). Hint, for double the resolution or reduce it by half, the common set is `kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1` for both conv or transposeconv,